# Equal area projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reprojection-mathematics, shape-area, equal-area

In which projection I should project a polygon of a country to get the right area in the attribute table without a distortion? For example greenland

Comment: Have read here:

Comment: ....got timed out somehow. Here is the link :http://axismaps.github.io/thematic-cartography/articles/projections.html